# Removing everything after specific character

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing a Qt application. I have some Strings like :

(Sub String before @)

```
43243263@example.com

325754754@example.com
```

I want to use

```
43243263

325754754
```

How to do that?

Comment: Duplicate of [Removing everything after character (and also character)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392405/removing-everything-after-character-and-also-character?rq=1)

Comment: Are you working with `std::string` or `QString`? That might change if the question is a duplicate..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `QString::indexOf` and `QString::mid` methods to extract the desired part.

```
QString str = "43243263@example.com";
QString desired = str.mid(0, str.indexOf("@"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you have `QString`.

```
QStringList partsList = yourString.split('@');

// your check here the length of list is 2
```

Your desired output `QString` will be at:

```
partsList.at(0)
```