# How do I find character in string and after that I extract the rest of string in C++

Tags: c++

So my problem is next:
I have youtube link entered as input, and I should print youtubeID as output.

So, perhaps I have this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szyKv63JB3s , I should print this "szyKv63JB3s", so I came to conclusion that I need to find that " = " in user inputed string and I should look to make new string called "ytID" or "result" and store youtubeID from the moment I find that " = " characther.

So I really don't have idea how should it be done... 
I mean I should go through string with for loop I guess, and after that I should store the part which will be called youtubeID, and I have problem there because I don't know how long is that link, I mean how much characthers it have, so I cannot really use for or while loops...

P.S This is not HOMEWORK, I just want to practice. :)

Comment: What about `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szyKv63JB3s&feature=youtu.be&t=49`? Little bit more complicated than finding `=`, no?

Comment: I would add if statment so if there's " = " characther found again, just break; :)
I should've also think about that, but do you have any idea of how to solve this what I asked for ? I mean I don't need code, I didn't came for that, I just came here for some pseudo-code

Comment: You question is way too broad. You need a tutorial. Or a book in C++. Such broad requests are off-topic on SO.

Comment: I got you what do you mean, but let's just take case that I get url like: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szyKv63JB3s", I mean that always can be found... Look there's other option, you can go through string on very beginning to check if there's more than 1 "=" characters and if there are more than 1 "=" characters, just warn user and bring him back to point where they need to again enter link, but you also give them description of what ytLink should look like

Comment: Like I said I just need that little description of what shall I do to go through string, find that "=" char., and how to store rest of string after "=" char. 
Just something like pseudo of it

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/substr , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of

Comment: One common way to go is: 1) use regular expression to parse the URI parts, 2) use e.g. `std::getline` to parse the key value pairs of the query, 3) take the value that corresponds to key "v".

Comment: Thank you, sir ! 
Literally solved my question with this, like I was knocking my head with pointless for loops basically

Comment: @ezegoing That also makes sense, but I find it easier to look for "=" string, it's same, because if there's something else in that link, not just ID, that whole rest of string will be printed no matter what, so yeah


I solved this problem with these two simple lines:
 <pre> int pos = ytlink.find("=");
 ytID = ytlink.substr(pos + 1);
 cout << ytID;
<code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just search for the character `=` as you mentioned in the question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>


std::string_view extractYoutubeId(std::string_view const link) {
    auto const off = link.find('=');
    if (off == std::string_view::npos)
        return std::string_view{};
    return link.substr(off + 1);
}

int main() {
    auto const& link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ";
    std::cout << extractYoutubeId(link);
}
```

Output: `dQw4w9WgXcQ`

Comment: Yeah this is quite advanced for me, since u used this "string_view" which I never heard for, also "auto const".... But thank you for help also

Comment: I mean I found my way with a help of @"Jesper Juhl", it's kind of easier

Answer (score 2):

you should give a look at this post : 
    [Removing everything after character (and also character)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392405/removing-everything-after-character-and-also-character)

A solution could be as simple as :

```
theString.substr( theString.find('=') ) ;
```